How to fix type mismatch with Series<dynamic, *> in Dart?
While working on a Flutter application in Android Studio, I encountered a type mismatch error in Dart that I have been unable to resolve. The error occurs when I try to assign a List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>> to a parameter expecting a List<Series<dynamic, String>>. I am using the charts_flutter package for displaying charts. Here's the exact error message from my terminal:

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/charts_demo.dart:50:7: Error: The argument type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Series<dynamic, String>>'.

This error appears when I try to pass seriesList, which is dynamically defined, to a BarChart that expects a more specific type.
Below is the snippet of code where the issue occurs:
Code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'dart:math';

class ChartsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartsDemoState createState() => _ChartsDemoState();
}

class _ChartsDemoState extends State<ChartsDemo> {
  late List<charts.Series<dynamic, String>> seriesList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    seriesList = _createRandomData();
  }

  static List<charts.Series<Sales, String>> _createRandomData() {
    final random = Random();
    return [
      charts.Series<Sales, String>(
        id: "Sales",
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: List.generate(5, (i) => Sales('${2015 + i}', random.nextInt(100))),
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Charts Demo")),
      body: charts.BarChart(seriesList, animate: true),
    );
  }
}

class Sales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  Sales(this.year, this.sales);
}





Removing the typing on List should work but that's not best practice. It's possible that Series is not typing properly against <Sales, String>, other parts of your code may have to confirm this. Please share

you cant assign variabel with different data type, try print both runtimeType. Then change one of them to make same data type
